# Index on cypher doesn't update in transaction

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

If I'm **inside a transaction** cypher index returns nothing, but if I use SpringRest or commit before run cypher query it returns the node. This is the context: I have an object with an index and I'm inserting it through `Neo4jTemplate.save()`, if I use `GraphRepository.findByPropertyValue()` to get the object saved it returns **ok**, but if I use `Cypher` with index it returns **nothing**. The `Cypher` only returns the object if I get it by nodeID.

```
@NodeEntity
public class Group {
    @GraphId
    private Long nodeId;
    @Indexed(indexName = "groupIndex")
    private Long id;
}
```

OK when using:

```
GraphRepository.findByProperty("id", 1L);
Neo4jTemplate.query("START n=node(1) RETURN n");
```

NOTHING when using:

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("id", 1L);
Neo4jTemplate.query("START n=node:groupIndex(id={id}) RETURN n", params);
```

Comment: This query uses the node-id not your id: `Neo4jTemplate.query("START n=node(1) RETURN n");` See, below, Nicolas is right, use numeric=false for your annotation to have the correct cypher query work: `Neo4jTemplate.query("START n=node:groupIndex(id=\"1"\) RETURN n");` btw. you should use a parameter instead: `Neo4jTemplate.query("START n=node:groupIndex(id={id}) RETURN n");` and pass a map with "id"->"1" as parameter.

Comment: The result is the same. The problem is when I'm inside a transaction using index on cypher returns nothing when I look for a node inserted on same transaction but when using GraphRepository.findByProperty() it returns the node.

Comment: Cypher will never return anything at least not in embedded mode, in REST mode the indexing will be String by default. In embedded mode numeric values are indexed as numeric by default (backwards compatibility) you have to use `@Indexed(numeric=false)` to index it as a string.

Comment: You're right Michael, I changed to (numeric=false) it returns the nodes, but the main problem persists. If I try to get the node by index inserted on same transaction before commit cypher doesn't return it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your Query, you're asking for the index in a String format, but in your first examples you're specifying them as a number.

If memory serves me correctly, you cannot perform Cypher query's on Numerically stored indexes. You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177584/neo4j-and-lucene-multikey-queries-or-should-i-use-cypher/10187843#10187843).

The easy solution here is to store that ID fields as a non-numeric by chaning your `@Indexed` to be `@Indexed(indexName = "groupIndex", numeric = false)`

Comment: Sorry man, I forgot to say that it just happens inside a transaction, the query returns the node if I commit before run it. About the quotes I get an error if I remove them. I think the quotes are required when using index doesn't matter if the index is numeric or not.

Comment: So you're saying that the Query works when doing the `groupIndex` now?

Comment: The Query works but returns nothing when I'm inside a transaction and look for the object inserted inside it. If I insert the object, commit the transaction and run the query it returns the node correctly.